# Change class based on radio button in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've build a webapp about TV Shows as a practice to learn AngularJS. What I need now, though, is to change a class based on which radio button is checked.

This is the view:

```
<div id="image" class="no-selection"></div>

<div ng-class="{ {{ show.name }}:'col-md-12 chosen', !{{ show.name }}:'col-md-12' }[tvshow.chosen]"  ng-repeat="show in shows"

        <input type="radio" name="checkbox" ng-model="tvshow.chosen" ng-value="show.name">

</div>

<tt>TV Show = {{tvshow.chosen | json}}</tt><br/>
```

How do I go from here to change the class of `#image`

Answer (score 0):

have you tired the [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)?

```
class="{{tvshow.chosen}}" 
ng-class="{useThis: true, dontUse: returnFalse()}"
ng-class="['this', 'and', 'that']"
```

Comment: It shouldn't be named to the tvshow name though. It should just change to class `SomethingSelected` if the associated radio button is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class directive as `<div id="image" ng-class="{classname : tvshow.chosen, classname : !tvshow.chosen}"></div>`and her is the docs for more information https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: It shouldn't be named to the tvshow name though. It should just change to class `SomethingSelected` if the associated radio button is checked.

Comment: when you check the radio button bound that change to ng-modle then ng-class="{SomethingSelected : ng-modlevariable}"

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
        <div id="image" ng-class="{show1:'show1class', show2:'show2class', false:'no-selection'}[tvshow.chosen]">
          {{tvshow.chosen}}
        </div>

        <div class="col-use-select" ng-repeat="show in shows">
          <input id="{{show.name}}" type="radio" name="checkbox" ng-model="tvshow.chosen" ng-value="show.name">
          <label for="{{show.name}}">{{show.name}}</label>
        </div>
      </body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wYqNvesYSJTEol4eHv0L?p=preview

Comment: So, because I want the class to be assigned to the associated div for every radio button, I used your idea and made it into this: `<div class="col-md-12 sidebar-element" ng-class="{ {{ show.name }}:'col-md-12 chosen', !{{ show.name }}:'col-md-12' }[tvshow.chosen]"  ng-repeat="show in shows">`

Doesn't work, though :(

Comment: @User183849481 i updated the plunker version. you can build your own expression object in controller.